# C *char pointer to char array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have a *char pointer and a char array.
How can I put the value of the pointer in the char array? I've tried

```
uint8_t i;
char a[10];
char *b = "abcdefghi";
for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    a[i] = b[i];
}
printf("%s", a);
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: You could use `sprintf(a, "%p", b);` to get the pointer into the buffer `a`. However, it could be that the buffer is not wide enough, depending on the size of the pointer. Actually, check out `snprintf()`, which should be safer.

Comment: what you miss is the fact that C strings are NULL terminated in fact b contains "abcdefghi\0".

Comment: you can: `for(i = 0; a[i] = b[i]; i++);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of `a` is `10`, so is the length of `b`(including the null terminator). Change

```
for(i = 0; i < 9; i++)
```

to

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Comment: yes strings are NULL terminated in C, last char be '0'.

Comment: @philippelhardy Not `'0'`, but `'\0'` or `0`

Comment: yes i should not have used enclosing '. 0x0 the byte 0.

Comment: thanks This Answer is really help full  butThere is One little Mistake just Like (i = 0; i <= 9; i++)

Comment: @Rio `i < 10` is more clear than `i <= 9` in C-based languages, so it's preferred.

Comment: as your wish but both are perfect According to our understanding

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is right.

Juts change `i<10` in your for loop.

There are 10 elements in your char array and the array index is from `0-9`.

Comment: `strlen()` in each iteration is bad idea

Answer (score -1):

yet another variant:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char a[10];
    char *c = a;
    char *b = "abcdefghi";
    for(; *c = *b; ++c, ++b);
    printf("%s", a);
    return 0;
}
```

but `strcpy()` will work faster in any case, since it is often written in assembly language for a specific architecture